# How to group report vertically and horizontally at the same time?

Tags: c#, matrix, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer

I use `Matrix` in my `RDLC` report to group Vertically And horizontally at the same time .But i get a result differs a little from my target .

***My Report is like this :***

[image]

---

***The Current result is something like that:***

[image]

---

***My target should be like that :***

[image]

---

***My query dataset is like this :***

```
Company year  Tot1           tot2
3001    2016  60.7332300    58.093040
3001    2015  66.1421300    64.754000
3002    2016  211.3360000   94.113000
3002    2015  169.8230000   168.082000
```

---

ACCORDING TO `alejandro zuleta` Request :

[image: ![enter image description here]

How to change the report to achieve my target ?

Comment: Can you please include your source query?

Comment: @iamdave :i edit my question ,Could you take a look please

Comment: Sorry, I would like to see your query, not the resultant dataset.

Comment: @iamdave it's a big query

Comment: That's fine.  If you can't put it here within the character limit, link to a pastebin or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change your query and you are comparing two different years, you can hardcode the `Total 1` and `Total 2`.

[image]

I created four columns and used these expressions:

`=MAX(Fields!Year.Value)` Will return 2016

`=MIN(Fields!Year.Value)` will return 2015

To get the values use:

Total 1 for 2016:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Year.Value=MAX(Fields!Year.Value),Cdbl(Fields!Tot1.Value),0))
```

Total 1 For 2015:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Year.Value=MIN(Fields!Year.Value),Cdbl(Fields!Tot1.Value),0))
```

Total 2 for 2016:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Year.Value=MAX(Fields!Year.Value),Cdbl(Fields!Tot2.Value),0))
```

Total 2 For 2015:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Year.Value=MIN(Fields!Year.Value),Cdbl(Fields!Tot2.Value),0))
```

You will get:

[image]

> Note no columns groups were created. `Category` was added as Row
>   Group.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Could i ask if this's a `table` or `matrix` please ?

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare, I used a table, but you can also use a matrix just be sure there is no column groups set. If you use a table delete the `details` in row groups pane, leaving only Company group.

Comment: I get `#Error` with every expression like that :`=SUM(IIF(Fields!Year.Value=MAX(Fields!Year.Value),Fields!Tot1.Value,0))`

Comment: How Could you do something like that without Grouping by `year`

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare, I don't need to group by year because I am getting the year using MIN and MAX function. And I am using a conditional sum to sum up only the values for 2016 (MAX year). that's why I use IIF(this year = max year, then sum the total 1 value otherwise sum 0.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare, could you add a screenshot of your current tablix.

Comment: I add the screenshot,Could you take a look plz?

Comment: I change the first Cell to `=Fields!Tot1.Value` just to try

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare, I've updated the expressions give them a try.

Comment: I get the same `#Error` , Don't know why , just if it make a difference `Tot1,Tot2 ..` are of type `Decimal`

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare, check what is the error you are getting in the Error List pane. Are you getting the years correctly?

Comment: No error in compile time , the error in run time , and yeah i get the year correctly, because it appears right in the header   `=MAX(Fields!Year.Value)` =2016 , i edit my question and take a simple screenshot from the runtime error

Comment: try to change use table instead of matrix but still the same error

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare, try the last update I've converted explicitely the Tot value to an SSRS aggregable data type.

Comment: I can't find any words to thank you , really I'm grateful

Comment: It works like a magic , Could i ask if it's the best way to group vertically in my case , or there are more better ways

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare, It depends on your dataset structure. the best way should be using the Row Groups and Column groups panels. But sometimes (like this one) you will manage to get the desired presentation. However, the best practice is structure your dataset at source (SQL), avoiding long report processing time.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would have your total type and your year as just two columns in your dataset, on which you can then group in your matrix.

To achieve this, you would simply have column grouping levels as follows:

> --TotalType
>   ----Year
>   ------Details